# Umbraco - Add spacing under element

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

The question might seem stupid. but i really can't find what i should type on the "Add spacing under element" text box to achieve the spacing from the CMS and not hard-coded.
In an element properties you can see this window:

[image: Umbraco Element Properties]

Umbraco version 7.2.5 assembly: 1.0.5610.18894
Free License for now but planning to get one this week.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? add spacing under which element?

Comment: under a "Full width block"

Comment: and what is that? Is it a property editor? are you using any package or something?

Comment: it is the default install from webmatrix with just one update to the latest version. it has only umbraco forms add on (trial).

Comment: can you tell the exact location of these settings? I have never seen this... Like backoffice -> Settings -> Templates etc.

Comment: have a look at this video: [link](http://screencast.com/t/taxDEVTxZP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I got your point. You are using Grid Layout.
By default Umbraco Grid layout datatype have setting class and styling background image as below
[image]

This can be found in Developer -> Datatypes - > datatype you have created with "Grid Layout", You can find data type name in Setting->Document types -> Name of home doc type -> generic properties

You can change settings and styles by clicking edit, it contains json data as below. This is default value

For setting

```
[
  {
    "label": "Class",
    "description": "Set a css class",
    "key": "class",
    "view": "textstring"
  }
]
```

For Style

```
[
  {
    "label": "Set a background image",
    "description": "Set a row background",
    "key": "background-image",
    "view": "imagepicker",
    "modifier": "url({0})"
  }
]
```

Get full details on [link](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/using-umbraco/backoffice-overview/property-editors/built-in-property-editors-v7/Grid-Layout/Settings-and-styles)

> Now your scenario.

I think according to description, you have used this to add padding-bottom or margin-bottom style on the element. So you must use values like "20px" or "10px". Try only numbers like "10" if this don't work

Comment: Thanks for your help. You did a great job and a gave me an answer above expectations.